# Apps are disabled when debug is set to False

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a blog while using the django rest framework (using version 2.3).

When I set the debug flag to False, the admin features disable my custom apps (such as comments, post, etc).
The authentication portion still seems functional though (users, groups).

Is there a way to override this at all?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

I had to put the admin urls after my app urls.
Guess the apps needed to be resolved before the admin.

Nice to know when I have to put things in production for the future.